# Python Convert PDF to XLSX

Tags: python, pandas, pypdf

Can anyone of you help me convert a PDF file that contains tables to XLSX?

PDF original

[image: 1]

Invalid URL

[image: 2]

```
from path_name_mappings import destination_filed_xlsx
from path_name_mappings import destination_path_pdf
import tabula
import pandas as pd
import os

def pdf_to_excel(pdf_file_path, excel_file_path):
    tables = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_file_path, pages='all', multiple_tables=True)

    with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        for i, table in enumerate(tables):
            table = table.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0': 'Godzina'})
            sheet_name = f'Sheet{i+1}'
            table.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

def process_all_pdfs(pdf_folder, excel_folder):
    for pdf_file in os.listdir(pdf_folder):
        if pdf_file.endswith(".pdf"):
            pdf_file_path = os.path.join(pdf_folder, pdf_file)
            pdf_base_name = os.path.splitext(pdf_file)[0]
            excel_file_path = os.path.join(excel_folder, pdf_base_name + ".xlsx")
            pdf_to_excel(pdf_file_path, excel_file_path)

# Example usage
process_all_pdfs(destination_path_pdf, destination_filed_xlsx)
```

Can anyone help me correct the code to correctly export PDF files to XLSX while maintaining the PDF format? This is very important for me to continue working on the project

Comment: Please update your question with what your specific desired result/improvement is. "Make it better" isn't a valid question here.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is mo easy way to program styles from PDF into other office formats, HTML output is most likely to work for text, followed by DocX.

But all are frequently problematic without any cells in a PDF, so the styling in Excel is best applied in Excel by copy and paste.

You could for the simpler cases use a macro to pick and paste colours or fonts but usually far simpler to set how you want them, since you have the review copy open anyway for checking.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a script that will do it for me, and the problem is with formatting

Comment: However, I am not able to get the source in XLSX from the office, I only have access to PDF, and I chose this way to read the data from PDF in a good way, i.e. I have the date, e.g. 30/10/2023 and the time 8:27, so I find the value assigned in X/Y axes, i.e. 7 labs
room 111 Building 5